# using printf to include both variable output and command

Tags: bash, unix, printf, fastq

I am trying to get the number of reads for my fastq files, and I wanted the output to also include the name of my files. I've found a solution online that almost works, but still not getting the right output. Example:

My file names:

```
12S_C-T1-045_F_filt.fastq.gz
12S_C-T1-PL_F_filt.fastq.gz
...
```

The code I have found:

```
for file in ./*.fastq.gz
do 
    file_name=$(basename -s .fastq $file)
    printf "$file_name\t$(cat ${file} | wc -l)/4|bc\n" >> no_reads_12S.txt
done
```

The output:

```
12S_C-T1-045_F_filt.fastq.gz 114/4|bc
12S_C-T1-PL_F_filt.fastq.gz 26455/4|bc
...
```

So, clearly is not doing the calculation right--the numbers are not even correct. How should I fix this? I've tried also doing this:

```
for file in ./*.fastq.gz
do 
    file_name=$(basename -s .fastq.gz $file)
    echo "$file_name"
    echo $(zcat $file | wc -l)/4|bc
done
```

Which works, but then it gives me the filenames and read numbers in separate rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Show the output you get.  And sample data files.  See [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the 2nd script, would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./*.fastq.gz; do
    file_name=$(basename -s .fastq.gz "$file")
    printf "%s\t%d\n" "$file_name" "$(echo $(zcat "$file" | wc -l) / 4 | bc)"
done
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
for file in ./*.fastq.gz; do file_name=$(basename -s .fastq.gz "$file"); printf "%s\t%d\n" "$file_name" "$(echo $(zcat "$file" | wc -l) / 4 | bc)"; done
```

As the synopsis of `printf` is:

> printf FORMAT [ARGUMENT]...

we need to feed strings as the arguments. the 1st argument `"$file_name"`
will be obvious. The second argument `"$(echo $(zcat "$file" | wc -l) / 4 | bc)"` may require explanation. First the command `$(zcat "$file" | wc -l)`
is substituted with the line count as the output of the command pipeline.
Then the outer command will look like `$(echo <number> / 4 | bc)` then it
is substituted with the result of `bc` and passed to `printf`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the error in the file extension. that was a mistake on my part and i edited in the question above!

Comment: also, it works! n_n thank you so much! so the first part, after printf is how it's displaying the 2 structures following up? i'm not familiar w/ printf.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've added small explanation about the usage of `printf` with command output. Hope it will help.